# Should I use Observer pattern to notify Customer object when the customer's Account has made deposit transaction?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I do have Customer and Account business objects which implement `ICustomer` and `IAccount` respectively. I also have service layers for each business objects. `AccountService` (`addAccount` , `deposit()`, `withdraw()` methods) and CustomerService (`addCustomer`, `addAdressForACustomer`, `removeCustomer()` etc.. methods).

I want my system to user Observer patter so that I send email notification to customers  when one of the transactions (`withdraw()` or `deposit()` methods succeed). I understand that the customer is the observer and the account is the subject which should notify the customer. But customer can have different accounts and should be notified for each of them when a transaction occurs.

Should I add `notifyCustomer()` methods to my Account business object or in the service by extending Observable Java class? I am confused a bit how to implement that. Should Observer pattern a good thing to use it in this case?

Thanks

Here is a sample code of my business objects

```
package business;

import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class Account implements IAccount {

    private int accountNumber;
    private IParty owner;



    public Account(int accountNumber, IParty owner, BigDecimal balance) {
        super();
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    private BigDecimal balance;

    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    public IParty getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(IParty owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }



}


package business;

import java.util.Date;

public class Person extends Party implements IPerson {

    private Date birthDate;
    public Person(String name, IAddress address,Date birthDate) {
        super(name, address);
        this.birthDate=birthDate;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }


}


package service;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

import business.Account;
import business.IAccount;
import business.IAccountEntry;
import business.IParty;

public class AccountService implements IAccountService {


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#createAccount()
     */
    IDaoService daoService;
    @Override
    public void createAccount(){

        //IAccount account= new Account(accountNumber,party,amount) ;
        //daoService.create();

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#removeAccount(business.IAccount)
     */
    public void removeAccount(){



    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#addAccountEntry(business.IAccountEntry)
     */
    @Override
    public void addAccountEntry(IAccountEntry accountEntry){

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#removeAccountEntry(business.IAccountEntry)
     */
    @Override
    public void removeAccountEntry(IAccountEntry accountEntry){

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#deposit(business.IAccount, java.math.BigDecimal)
     */
    @Override
    public void deposit(IAccount account, BigDecimal amount){

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#withdraw(business.IAccount, java.math.BigDecimal)
     */
    @Override
    public void withdraw(IAccount account, BigDecimal amount){

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#getCurrentBalance()
     */
    @Override
    public BigDecimal getCurrentBalance(){
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#findAccountsByParty(business.IParty)
     */
    @Override
    public List<IAccount> findAccountsByParty(IParty party){
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see service.IAccountService#findAccountByAccountNumber(int)
     */
    @Override
    public IAccount findAccountByAccountNumber(int accountNumber){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAccount(IAccount account) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should you use Observer Pattern? It is probably a good idea since you can cleanly separate concerns, simplify your design and not clutter business logic everywhere.

**Should I add notifyCustomer() methods to my Account business object or in the service by extending Observable Java class?**

That is a definite NO.  `Observerable` is a Java 1 class and was poorly designed. First, it's a class, not an interface, so you have to extend it to use it.  This severely limits your design options.  Instead make your own interface and let your classes implement that interface instead to do the observing.

Since you want an example and you have multiple accounts:

```
public interface AccountObserver{

   public void withdrawl(IAccount from, BidDecimal amount);

   public void deposit(IAccount to, BigDecimal amount);

}
```

I included an `IAccount` reference so clients know which account was updated since you want to manage multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When you say "Let's your classes implement that interface", are talking about the business object class Account to implement AccountObserver? How about the subject (customer)? Should I do the same thing? Thanks again.

Comment: `Account` should not implement `AccountObserver`, whatever is the customer should implement `AccountObserver`.  However, some object (`Account`, or `AccountService`)  should keep track of which customers are observing what accounts so they can be notified correctly

Comment: Great! but one thing is not still clear. How about the subject? Should it be the Customer object, where we will have update() method? And I think in the above AccountObserver, we should also include notify() and addAccounts() . right?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenarios you can maintain list of account for each Observer. So that all accounts can be updated when a model gets changed

```
public class Account(account)
{

List<Customer> listCustomers = new ArrayList();
public addRelatedCustomer(Customer customer)
{
listCustomers.add(customer)
}

public updateAccount(int balance)
{
this.account.balance=balance;
updateAllUsers();
}

public void updateAllUsers()
{
customer.notify();

}


public class Customer 
{
public void notify(Account account)
{
//sample code
}

}


public class Demo{

Account ac = new Account();

Customer c1= new Customer();
Customer c2= new Customer();

ac.add(c1);
ac.add(c2);


//// This will trigger notification to all customers
ac.updateAccount(5000);






}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to update accounts. It's the other way round. When a an account is updated, I want to notify customers.

Comment: Ksv. I don't think you get the point. One account belongs to one customer only . so we dont need to have list of customers in an account. But a customer can have multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

Even though there can be multiple accounts for a customer, each of them will have 1:1 correspondence. Means an account will have relation to an owner (the owner will however be the same if he owns multiple accounts).

Now whenever an Account is updated, you can send a notification to the attached owner via a callback on the owner or you can have a AccountObserver as suggested by @dkatzel. This will be helpful in case you have observers other than the owner (for eg - batchjob, banks transaction sys,audit sys etc). In this case you can  register the listeners and can maintain a List of them

```
class Account{
 List<AccountObserver> allListeners;

 public void deposit(Double amt){
   doDeposit();
   for(AccountObserver o: allListeners){
      o.notify(this,amt);
   }
  ...
 }

  class Customer implements AccountObserver{
   Account act;
   ...
   registerMe(){
    act.register(this);//adds to the listener list of Account
   }
  }
```